# javascript object for storing grid data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to store some grid data (cell sizes and coords) for drawing.

I'm new to pure js, so I having some difficulties.

Right now I calculate it like this:

```
  var W = document.width;
  var H = document.height;

  var w = [80, null, 80, 100];
  w[1] = W - w[0] - w[2] - w[3];
  var x = [0, w[0], w[0] + w[1], w[0] + w[1] + w[2], w[0] + w[1] + w[2] + w[3]];

  var h = [null, 20, 100];
  h[0] = H - w[1] - w[2];
  var y = [0, h[0], h[0] + h[1]];
```

But this is ugly.

I'd like to store data into some object, and access fields like this:

```
var grid = new Grid ([80, null, 80, 100], [null, 20, 100]);
// 'null' means that value shall be recalculated on window resized
var x1 = grid.x[1];
var w1 = grid.w[1];
// etc ..
// plus, somewhere inside Grid: window.addEventListener('resize', .... )
```

I suppose that this problem was solved many times (but I cant find any), and I don't want to "invent bicycle".

Could you please suggest any solution? .. or may be link to corresponding article?

Comment: could you explain - in `var w = [80, null, 80, 100];` each item stands  for what? same goes to `var h = [null, 20, 100];`

Comment: @TamilVendhan `w` stands for `width` for each cell; I define width for cells #0,2,3, but width for cell#1 (which is null) is dinamically calculated as  `window.width - sum. widths of all cells` (so `w[0] + w[1] + w[2] + w[3] == window.width`). The same for h(height).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: your english is fine. The question is easily understandable.

Now then, for the actual question: it looks like you're wanting a *class*. JavaScript classes are funny things. There is a lot of documentation on how to write classes in JavaScript. In particular, I'd recommend looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752868/does-javascript-have-classes), [here](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/) (not strictly about classes but still has a lot of good info), and [here (shameless self-plug)](http://emallson.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/javascript-classes-for-c-programmers-and-others-too-part-i/).

Inside your class, you can use `Object.defineProperty` to do stuff like:

```
Object.defineProperty(Grid.prototype, 'x', {
    'get': function() {
        /* do some calculations */
        return value;
    }
};

// later on
var x = myGrid.x;
```

Alternatively, you could use a bog-standard function:

```
Grid.prototype.x = function() {
    /* do some calculations */
    return value;
}

// later on
var x = myGrid.x();
```

As far as resizing goes, you're definitely on the right track with attaching an event listener to the `resize` event. I'd recommend using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) for that; it'll help in the long run. Your code would look something like:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event) {
    /* loop over values */
    /* if value is null, recalculate */
});
```

Comment: In my question `Grid` is `MyOwnClassThatHandleData`, so, I think, there is no need to modify `prototype`. Or not? I mean `Grid.prototype.x = function() {...}` => `Grid.x = function() {...}`

Comment: `Grid.x = function() {...}` will assign a static function to `Grid`. In order to use it, you'd call `Grid.x()`. `Grid.prototype.x = function() {...}` will add a function to the `Grid` prototype which can then be accessed as a per-instance function (like `var grid = new Grid(); grid.x()`) that can use the `this` pointer. They are not the same.

If you want multiple instances of `Grid`, then use `Grid.prototype.x` for your functions. If you want a single 'instance', then use `Grid.x`.